# Concepts implied by the word 'realize'

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, concept

When saying 'I realized something' does this imply that I became aware on my own? If someone had explained something to me and only after did I understand, can I still use 'I realized'? Or do I need to use alternative phrasing to imply that I required assistance to become aware.

Comment: _Realize_ can refer to either method of coming to understand. If you want to refer only to your unaided conclusion, you can use _figure out_ to take sole credit. The important point to realize about using _realize_ is that it's a **factive** predicate -- it presupposes its complement, which means that the speaker is taking it for granted and expects the addressee to do the same. Presuppositions can't be denied, which makes them troublesome. So you can't say *_He doesn't realize the earth is flat_, because the earth isn't flat.

Comment: There are two basic definitions of "realize".  The first means to come to recognize or understand some idea or concept.  (This is by far the most common meaning.)  The second means to more or less literally make something "real" (by, eg, following a blueprint to build a house).  For the first definition it's generally implied that there was an "Aha! moment" on your part, but there's no strong implication as to whether or not someone had to beat you with a stick to provoke this moment.